# How does one reference files that are on the same level on a web server?

Tags: file, reference, filesystems, include, include-path

[image: I want to reference header.inc in register.php how do I do it?]

I want to reference header.inc in register.php how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From register.php you could use this for including:

```
<?php
  include('../includes/header.inc');
?>
```

To link to it just send your **href** or what have you to **`../includes/header.inc`**